# How to setup ELK in simple java project

Tags: java, log4j, logback, elk

I am new in ELK setup. I setup ELK in spring Boot microservice and running successfully but i want to setup ELK in simple Java project.

I have a simple JAVA project i am using Jar of that project in docker file.

Is there any way to setup ELK in Simple Java project?

Answer (score 0):

You can install ELK locally as docker image, then use it from your simple java project. 
A docker container should only run a process, so elk in the same project would not be a good idea. Why does it have to be a simple java project anyway? if you are building a container it make sense to make it a microservice...

Could you explain a bit more on why simple java?

So when you have two containers, make sure they run on the same network...

Cheers!

Comment: Actually i am using a maven project where i am using logger but i want that logging part with elk.

Comment: so you need only filebeats in the app configured to send the logs to an running instance of ELK. In your ELK instance, which in this case is another Container running somewhere or even locally, you can then analyse the collected logs...

Comment: Actually i am using jar file of that project where i am using Logger right now but i want to use ELK in that project.

Comment: So use filebeat as a log exporter. The logs should be sent to the ELK that runs somewhere in a different machine or your local docker...This favours loose coupling.

Comment: Actually i have a simple maven project and i want elk setup with that project using docker. Can you provide me example for that?

Comment: take a look at this ankit https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-getting-started.html